# Trouble adding 'rest-framework' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework

I installed the rest framework and now trying to add it to my Django project by adding it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` portion of the `settings.py` file, but I am getting this in my terminal whenever I try to run my server.

Backend is completely functional right up to the point I add `'rest-framework'` to `settings.py`

I would really appreciate any help with this as I have looking for a solution but can't find any

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\template\utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\template\backends\django.py",
line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templatetags\rest_framework.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (c:\users\admin\django\django\utils\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 76, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\template\utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\template\backends\django.py",
line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\template\backends\django.py",
line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\template\backends\django.py",
line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "c:\users\admin\django\django\template\backends\django.py",
line 125, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (c:\users\admin\django\django\utils\__init__.py)
```

This is the settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 's@q-i0&o-#cwoil9jv$3*e78lscfezur^v3w@vzpu61#56+3k#'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'music.apps.MusicConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Which Django Version you are using?

Comment: Can you please add `settings.py` code as well?

Comment: @ParthS007 I'm using Python 3.7.3, added the settings.py

Comment: I am asking about `Django` version.

Comment: @ParthS007 oh right sorry, it's 3.0 development version

Comment: Django latest stable release is `2.2.2`. Please use this.

Comment: @ParthS007 I'm getting this when I try to update so appears I have the latest version: Requirement already up-to-date: Django in c:\users\admin\django (3.0.dev20190619110352)

Comment: @ParthS007 I changed the Django version and it worked! thanks so much.

Comment: Great! Always Use Stable version when using in Project.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command using `PIP`:

`pip install djangorestframework`

After going through Error logs, I think  `six` is also missing here:

`pip install six`

I hope it helps

Comment: Install `six` module also. It is also missing according to logs.

Comment: That's what I get from the terminal since all the missing modules are already installed: 
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (1.12.0)

Comment: Are you using Virtual enviornment?

Comment: No I am not using Virtual Env

Answer (score 0):

`rest_framework` is trying to import `six` from `django.utils` yet it  has [since been removed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis) in Django **3.0** and higher.

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templatetags\rest_framework.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
```

You may want to downgrade your Django version to perhaps 2.2, or create a patch by
creating a new file *six.py* in `django.utils` and importing `six`:

```
import six
```

and install `six` in your environment:

```
pip install six
```